# Python coding/ decoding cipher

Tags: python, python-3.x, caesar-cipher

I am trying to encode and then decode this function in python using cipher encryption. I wrote this function. how do I change this function so that it encodes both lower and uppercase letters?

```
def encrypt(message, key):
  alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  encMessage=""

  for character in message:
      if character in alphabet:
          index = alphabet.find(character)
          newPosition = (index+key)%26
          newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
          encMessage+=newCharacter
      else:
          encMessage+=character

  return encMessage
```

Comment: Use `character.lower()` to get the lowercase version of the letter

Comment: `(index+key)%26` is not guaranteed to be an alphanumeric character , by the way

Comment: @Barmar in the for loop or above the for loop?

Comment: How can it be above the for loop? The `character` variable isn't defined there.

Comment: But you could also just do `message = message.lower()` before the loop.

Comment: Did you really write this function? It's exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716794/python-encoding-decoding-using-caesar-cipher)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the alphabet with uppercase letters. You will also need to update the modulo operation to get your `newPosition`.

```
def encrypt(message, key):

  # Extend your alphabet
  alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  alphabet += alphabet.upper()

  encMessage=""

  for character in message:
      if character in alphabet:
          index = alphabet.find(character)

          # Use the correct modulo
          newPosition = (index+key) % len(alphabet)

          newCharacter = alphabet[newPosition]
          encMessage+=newCharacter
      else:
          encMessage+=character

  return encMessage
```

Comment: Did you miss the comment in the other question where he admitted that he has multiple SO accounts and he wrote both questions?

Comment: I did not, should I remove the notice? What do you recommend, you seem to be more aware of what is going on.

Comment: Just remove the notice

Comment: Done, thanks for your work to figure out what was going on here.